# My e-mail is being used to send spam, what can I do?

Tags: email, smtp, spam-prevention

I am renting my own domain from a German hoster, and have created 4 e-mail accounts on it. All was well for 5+ years.

For about a week now, one of those accounts receives around 5 e-mails per day from "Mail Delivery System" (`Mailer-Daemon@server.pizzablogger.net`) with the subject "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender", and the following contents (I hope I censored all personal parts with XXX):

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent has not yet been delivered to one or more of its
recipients after more than 72 hours on the queue on server.pizzablogger.net.

The message identifier is:     XXX-0007Sr-EH
The subject of the message is: & Kommunikation
The date of the message is:    Sun, 28 Feb 2021 15:50:49 +0300

The addresses to which the message has not yet been delivered are:

  XXXx@yahoo.de
    host mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net [188.125.72.74]
    Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined MAIL FROM:<alex@XXX.de> SIZE=3380:
    421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes
  XXXto@yahoo.de
    host mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net [188.125.72.74]
    Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined MAIL FROM:<alex@XXX.de> SIZE=3380:
    421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes
  XXXem@yahoo.de
    host mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net [188.125.72.74]
    Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined MAIL FROM:<alex@XXX.de> SIZE=3380:
    421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes
  XXXh@yahoo.de
    host mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net [188.125.72.74]
    Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined MAIL FROM:<alex@XXX.de> SIZE=3380:
    421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes
  XXXe@yahoo.de
    host mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net [188.125.72.74]
    Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined MAIL FROM:<alex@XXX.de> SIZE=3380:
    421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes

No action is required on your part. Delivery attempts will continue for
some time, and this warning may be repeated at intervals if the message
remains undelivered. Eventually the mail delivery software will give up,
and when that happens, the message will be returned to you.


Reporting-MTA: dns; server.pizzablogger.net

Action: delayed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;XXXx@yahoo.de
Status: 4.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes

Action: delayed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;XXXo@yahoo.de
Status: 4.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes

Action: delayed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;XXXm@yahoo.de
Status: 4.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes

Action: delayed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;XXXh@yahoo.de
Status: 4.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes

Action: delayed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;XXXe@yahoo.de
Status: 4.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 162.144.XXX.XXX temporarily deferred due to unexpected volume or user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes


Return-path: <alex@XXX.de>
Received: from [81.16.9.222] (port=38385 helo=host-222.9.16.81.ucom.am)
    by server.pizzablogger.net with esmtpsa  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    (Exim 4.93)
    (envelope-from <alex@XXX.de>)
    id 1lGLXs-0007Sr-EH; Sun, 28 Feb 2021 12:51:37 +0000
Message-ID: <F0F543101BCFE15XXX@XXX.de>
From: "alex@XXX.de" <alex@XXX.de>
Subject: & Kommunikation
Date: Sun, 28 Feb 2021 15:50:49 +0300
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_1BE3_01D70DE9.7C8EBFB0"
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 15.4.3538.513
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V15.4.3538.513
```

- Can I do something about this? That is, is someone using my actual account login to send messages?
- Or is someone using his own mail server, and just filling in my address as the sender? (In which case I suspect I can do nothing)

I've already changed the password on this account, but the messages continue.

Comment: Probably the second. But I don't think there is enough info to be sure.

Comment: Is the IP address that says is being "temporary deferred" your IP address?

Comment: @DavidPostill what additional information can I provide to help clear it up?

Comment: @eventHandler I'm not sure since they reset often, but the hightest two bytes are currently *very* different, so I think that this is not my IP address.

Comment: Can you confirm whether `162.144.XXX.XXX` and/or `server.pizzablogger.net` are _your_ system or are they someone else's?

Comment: FWIW server.pizzablogger.net  is not an open relay.

Comment: @user1686 pizzablogger is not me. I don't know if that is another innocent host that's being misused, or if that is the source (or destination) of the spam mails being sent.